# Having a list of unretained id objects?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory-management, collections

How can I implement a class/object that has a reference to a bunch of non-retained `id` objects?

I want something similar to what `UIControl`/`NSControl` has: `addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action ...;` (in my case, though, I don't need the `UIControlEvents` part). I want to use this target/action pattern (and preferably stay away from the delegate pattern) but for that I need to make sure the targets added to my object are not retained or retain cycles might happen.

I think implementing my own array using `malloc`/`free` to make sure targets are not retained would be one solution, but all this hassle smells like there is already a solution implemented somewhere. Is there?

Comment: `malloc`? You can simply use a `std::vector`, or `std::list`, or ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X you can create an `NSPointerArray` that will keep weak references to its objects with [`+[NSPointerArray weakObjectsPointerArray]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPointerArray/weakObjectsPointerArray), or (if you want a dictionary) an [`NSMapTable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) which allows either or both of the keys and values to be held weakly.

Neither of those are available currently on iOS, but Core Foundation is. On either OS X or iOS you can use `CFArray` or `CFDictionary`, passing `NULL` for the callbacks to make the collection do no memory management of its contained objects. Be warned that if you try to use these as if they were their toll-free bridged Cocoa counterparts, the collection will not honor your non-retaining/non-copying desire. You'll have to use the CF functions to interact with them (or whip up a wrapper class).

You can also wrap your objects in `NSValue`s, using [`valueWithNonretainedObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-valueWithNonretainedObject_), and put those into a Cocoa collection (`NSDictionary`/`NSarray`). The collection will own the value, but the value will not own its object.

Comment: I would give more points but only 1 click in the ▲ is permitted. This worked very good!

Comment: Since I am in iOS the `NSPointerArray` was discarded (I guess this is one the classes that were/are not ported to iOS yet). I thought of `CFArray` too but as you pointed out toll-free bridge calls could become a bit cumbersome so I used `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]` and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `CFArrayRef`, specifying callbacks which do not perform ref count operations (or just 0 for the callbacks if you are feeling very lazy):

```
CFAllocatorRef allocator = 0;
const void **values = ...;
CFIndex numValues = ...;
const CFArrayCallBacks* const callBacks = 0;

CFArrayRef arr = CFArrayCreate(allocator, values, numValues, callBacks);
```